# How to make menu like this in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

Im new in flutter stuff can anyone help me to design layout list menu like this in flutter

> ListView(
> padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),    children: [
> Card(
> child: ListTile(
>
> ```
>     leading:  Text(
>       'List Item 1',
>     ),
>     trailing: Wrap(
>       spacing: 12,
>       children: <Widget>[
>       Text("Full Service"),
>         Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp,color: Colors.red,), 
>       ],
>     ),
>   )
> ),
> Card(
>   child: ListTile(
>     title:Text("List Item 2", style: mainNavigation,) ,
>   )
> ),
> ```
>
> ],    shrinkWrap: true,  ),

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout를 참고하세요.

Comment: Summarize problem, show what you've tried, and add some code. I'm just giving suggestions to get better.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak I have add the detail i want to make the "list item 1" and "list item 2" with no padding and want to apply style "style: mainNavigation" in list item 2 in all item,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ListTile` widget for making this UI. Try below example.

```
ListTile(
        leading:  Text(
          'Tipe Akun',
        ),
        trailing: Wrap(
          spacing: 12,
          children: <Widget>[
           Text("Full Service"),
            Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp,color: Colors.red,), 
          ],
        ),
      );
```

P.S :- Adjust your desire icon size

[image: Output]

Find more articles of `ListTile` widget :

[Various examples of ListTile](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-listtile/)

[ListTile Official Document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Comment: thank you I have made listview but dont know about "trailing" this save my day ^^ thank you sir